# Applying Class to First 5 and Last 5 Rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have built a simple example to what I wish to accomplish.  http://jsfiddle.net/helpinspireme/ejHFf/  What I would like to do is

- Count the number of table `<tr>`
- If the table has less then 6, then all get class `red`
- If more then 5 but less then 11, the first 5 get class `red` and the remaining with `black`
- If more then 10, add class `red` to the first 5 and then the last 5 add class `black` to.  The rows in between first 5 and the last 5 get no class.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want

```
    if (x < 6) {
        $(tooltips_id).addClass('red');
    } else if (x > tooltips_amount-5) {
        $(tooltips_id).addClass('black');
    } else {
        // else
    }
```

Comment: @Help Inspire Me why does no one understand how to give correct answers checkmarks? this guy needs a checkmark!

Comment: Stack Overflow makes me wait 8 minutes before checking the answer, so I had to wait.

Answer (score 1):

What have you already done? You pretty much describe the whole algorithm. Just use `slice` to get elements between indexes and `length` to get number of items.
To add a class, use `addClass`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly an answer to your question, as you may be needing this for reasons such as support of older browsers (it's especially notable that IE only supports my solution as of version 9). Though it may be good not to use this solution for that very same reason, I do think it is important to note that by more recent standards you can do this even without using any Javascript. You only CSS:

```
tr
{
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

tr:nth-child(-n+5)
{
    border: 1px solid red;
}


tr:nth-last-child(-n+5)
{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$("tr:lt(5)").css({ backgroundColor : "blue" });
$("tr:gt(5)").css({ backgroundColor : "red" });
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qJ3tP/220/)

Answer (score 0):

a fiddle for this
http://jsfiddle.net/9fmNG/

```
var rows = $('table tr');

rows.map(function( index, row){
    var allRows  = rows.size();

    if(index+1 <= 5)
        $(row).addClass('red');
    else if((index+1) >= (allRows-5)){
        $(row).addClass('black');    
    }               
})​
```

Comment: Please post your answer *here*. Otherwise, should JS Fiddle fall over (again...) your answer becomes useless. And there's no guarantee they won't clean up or delete old pages. Also: an [answer on meta-Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/130770) relating to link-only answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
var tooltip = function() {
    var tooltips_tr = $('#primary_table tr');
    var tooltips_amount = $(tooltips_tr).length;

    tooltips_tr.each(function(i){
        i+=1;
        if(tooltips_amount < 6) $(this).addClass('red');
        if(tooltips_amount > 5 && tooltips_amount < 11)
        {
            if(i<=5) $(this).addClass('red');    
            else $(this).addClass('black');
        }
        if(tooltips_amount > 10)
        {
            if(i<=5) $(this).addClass('red');    
            else if(i>tooltips_amount-5) $(this).addClass('black');
        }
    });
}
```

[**Example.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/ejHFf/10/)